# Can't see the returned JSON array on chart JS bar chart after changing MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, chart.js

**EDIT**

I consoled the `$.each` values and I've got: `12 undefined values`.

So I think the problem is when I am getting back the array, the success function can't read it here:

```
success:function(resp)
    {
      var costData = [];
      $.each(resp, function( key, row)
      {
        costData.push(row['cost']);
        console.log(row['cost']);
      });
...
```

**END EDIT**

I have a Chart JS div in my web page that get the income for each month.
After few months we saw that values are not correct due to an error in the SQL query that we made. But the chart was working well. I will show you the script first:

Here is the old PHP script that help us to get the values for each month:

```
<?php
//Set error reporting on
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

//Include connection file
require_once('../include/global.php');

//Json and PHP header
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$arr = array();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$id_logged = $_SESSION['login_id'];



$date1 = $_POST['current_year'];

    $res = array();
    $c = "cash";
    $i = "installment";
    //SUM of cash paid Month
    $sql = "SELECT 
    sum(cost) as cost

FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        sum(project_cost) as cost, 
        month(date_now) as month 
    FROM 
        dentist.patient_info 
    WHERE id_logged=:logged AND year(date_now)=:year_now AND payment_type=:pt 
    GROUP BY month(date_now)
    UNION
    SELECT 
        sum(payment), 
        month(date_now) 
    FROM 
       debt
    WHERE year(debt.date_now)=:year_now
    UNION SELECT 0,1
    UNION SELECT 0,2
    UNION SELECT 0,3
    UNION SELECT 0,4
    UNION SELECT 0,5
    UNION SELECT 0,6
    UNION SELECT 0,7
    UNION SELECT 0,8
    UNION SELECT 0,9
    UNION SELECT 0,10
    UNION SELECT 0,11
    UNION SELECT 0,12
) tmp
GROUP BY month";
$sqlStmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sqlStmt->bindValue(":logged", $id_logged);
$sqlStmt->bindValue(":pt", $c);
$sqlStmt->bindValue(":year_now", $date1);
$exec = $sqlStmt->execute();
$res = $sqlStmt->fetchAll();

echo json_encode($res);

?>
```

Now, after we made some changes into this script, I saw the values at the XHR, but the ChartJS stopped working. Here is the new script:

```
<?php
//Set error reporting on
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

//Include connection file
require_once('../include/global.php');

//Json and PHP header
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$id_logged = $_SESSION['login_id'];

$date1 = $_POST['current_year'];

$res = array();
$c = "cash";
$i = "installment";
//SUM of cash paid Month
for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
{
    $sql = "SELECT 
        sum(project_cost) as cost
    FROM 
        patient_info 
    WHERE id_logged=:logged AND year(date_now)=:year_now AND payment_type=:pt AND month(date_now)=:month";
    $sqlStmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $sqlStmt->bindValue(":logged", $id_logged);
    $sqlStmt->bindValue(":year_now", $date1);
    $sqlStmt->bindValue(":pt", $c);
    $sqlStmt->bindValue(":month", $i);
    $exec = $sqlStmt->execute();
    $sum1 = $sqlStmt->fetchAll();

    $sql2 = "SELECT 
        sum(payment) as cost
    FROM 
       debt
    WHERE id_logged = :logged AND year(date_now)=:year_now AND month(date_now) = :month";
    $sqlStmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $sqlStmt->bindValue(":logged", $id_logged);
    $sqlStmt->bindValue(":year_now", $date1);
    $sqlStmt->bindValue(":pt", $c);
    $sqlStmt->bindValue(":month", $i);
    $exec = $sqlStmt->execute();
    $sum2 = $sqlStmt->fetchAll();

    $sum = $sum1 + $sum2;

    $res[$i] = $sum;
}
echo json_encode($res);

?>
```

And here is the result at the console:

[image]

And here is the script of ChartJS:

```
$.ajax
  ({
    url: 'stat_income_test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {current_year: y},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success:function(resp)
    {
      var costData = [];
      $.each(resp, function( key, row)
      {
        costData.push(row['cost']);
      });


        var areaChartData = {
          labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"
          , "September", "October", "November", "December"],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Cash Income",
              strokeColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
              pointColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
              pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
              pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
              pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              data: costData
            }
          ]
        };
        var barChartCanvas = $("#barChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
        var barChart = new Chart(barChartCanvas);
        var barChartData = areaChartData;
        barChartData.datasets[0].fillColor = "#00c0ef";
        barChartData.datasets[0].strokeColor = "#00c0ef";
        barChartData.datasets[0].pointColor = "#00a65a";
        var barChartOptions = {
          //Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
          scaleBeginAtZero: true,
          //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
          scaleShowGridLines: true,
          //String - Colour of the grid lines
          scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
          //Number - Width of the grid lines
          scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
          //Boolean - Whether to show horizontal lines (except X axis)
          scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
          //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
          scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
          //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
          barShowStroke: true,
          //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
          barStrokeWidth: 2,
          //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
          barValueSpacing: 5,
          //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
          barDatasetSpacing: 1,
          //String - A legend template
          legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
          //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: true,

          // onAnimationComplete: function () {

          // var barChartData = this.chart.barChartData;
          // barChartData.font = this.scale.font;
          // barChartData.fillStyle = this.scale.textColor
          // barChartData.textAlign = "center";
          // barChartData.textBaseline = "bottom";

          // this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
          //     dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar) {
          //        barChartData.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y - 5);
          //     });
          //   })
          //}
        };

        barChartOptions.datasetFill = false;
        barChart.Bar(barChartData, barChartOptions);
      }
  });
```

The ChartJS is now like this:

[image]

It is getting correctly the year, and that's why I am seeing the result at the `XHR` but can't see it on the Chart. Any help is appreciated.